# Binary operations and proofs

Tags: binary, binary-operations

Let $\text{binary}(a)$ denote the binary representation of a base-$10$ number $a$. Are the following statements correct? If yes, where can I find the proofs?

> (1) $\text{binary}(a\times b)=\text{binary}(a)\times \text{binary}(b)$
>
> (2) $\text{binary}(a+b)=\text{binary}(a)+\text{binary}(b)$
>
> (3) $\text{binary}(a\times (b+c))=\text{binary}(a\times
> > b)+\text{binary}(a\times c)$

Comment: How do you define * ?

Comment: So, your question is about why do decimal fractions satisfy the field axioms, am I right?